# Windows 10: Can't get Rid of Malware Popups Notifications Spoofing Antivirus

Tags: windows-10, malware, notifications, popups, spoofing

I'm using Windows 10 Home, and I'm this popup, that keeps coming up at random times, at least hourly:
[image]

And, just a few minutes ago, this:
[image]

- I have disabled all popups in Internet Options.
- I ran Malwarebytes, with this output:
  [image]
- I chose to quarantine the suspect files
- Windows Security gave my PC a clean bill of health.
- Note the website mentioned in the popup: advtnow.com
- Strangely, I seem to be getting legitimate popups from Norton and McAfee (Both of which I did own for a while), prompting me to renew. I suspect the problem lies within Microsoft Edge.
- I have checked in Task Manager , but do not see any suspect processes. Since the popup appears when I just turn the machine on, I checked in Task Manager\Startup, but there's nothing there

Edit: Problem solved by @YisroelTech  in the comments, who suggested I restrict the Website in question's (Advtnow.com) access to Edge, by going to :edge://settings/content/notifications. @ Yisroel Tech: If you write it as a solution, I will accept it.

Comment: Yes; The problem is Microsoft Edge User Profile, simplest way, is to delete the entire user profile.  An alternative is to delete the cache files just for the malicious website. You can't expect a malware scanner to successful remove a Potentially Unwanted Program (PUP) while the browser is still running.  All of the "popups" in your screenshot are notifications from a (malicious) website.

Comment: This is not malware (which are software running on your PC) and therefore it was associated/closed in error.

Comment: @YisroelTech: Why do you believe it's not malware?

Comment: @MSIS, I see what is. The solution to stop those, is to remove this website from the allow list in the browser settings. Go in the broswer to ````edge://settings/content/notifications```` and remove all unrecognized websites - but specifically **advtnow.com** - from the Allow section.

Comment: @Yisroel Tech: Seems to have worked. I owe you a beer/wine/coffee of your choice if you drop by NYC. Or, if I get a job, a Kosher steak. Todah Ravah.

Comment:  I'm in NYC, what's the address?... 

Comment: @MSIS, BTW as you mentioned the Norton and pop-ups. You might still have them installed (not active since you didn't pay) check in Settings>Apps to see if they're there and it yes uninstall then.

Comment: I'm doing work here at Sbux, as we speak. One with shaved head.

Comment: @Yisroel Tech : If you write it as a solution, I will accept it.

Comment: I would if it was possible... someone incorrectly locked this question by associating it with a malware removal question that has a good answer already, the only issue is that this one isn't malware and the solutions there wouldn't've been helpful here. I hope that it will be reopned and then I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @YisroelTech- I actually agree it’s a duplicate (hence the reason I won’t vote to reopen), disagree that what’s being displayed isn’t malicious or malware just because the title of the question does not include the word “PUP” doesn’t mean the duplicate doesn’t answer this question. Feel free to answer the duplicate with a generic answer on how to remove PUP infections if you want.

Comment: @YisroelTech: I'm asking another question , maybe you can answer this and I can give you credit for this, since I couldn't last time.